# Is there a way to reset the OnClickListener to its default Android implementation?

Tags: android, android-edittext, onclicklistener

I have an editText to which I have set an OnClickListener, which is set to open a Dialog. But I have an option in the Dialog to let the user enter data into the editText by manually typing. I tried calling `setOnClickListener(null)`, but it makes the editText unresponsive.

As of yet I have tried a lot of things, but the only thing that works is recreating the activity by calling recreate(), but I'd rather the user not know that I'm recreating the Activity.
How do I reset the editText to behave normally like an Android editText works? (like opening the keyboard and entering data on tapping it)

Comment: It´s unclear what you are asking. Are you trying to delete the Input in the editText?

Comment: I want to remove my custom OnClickListener and let the user enter text, but as soon as I call call editText.setOnClickListener(null) the element stops responding to touch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
 editText.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        //do as u wish
                    }
                }
        );
```

to

```
  editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if(hasFocus){
//                        do as you wish
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a boolean member variable to keep track of when to allow user input and when to show the dialog.

`private boolean mShouldAllowInput = false;`

Then in your custom click listener you could do something like:

```
private View.OnClickListener editClickListener = new View.OnClickLIstener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(!mShouldAllowInput) {
            showDialog();
            mShouldAllowInput = true;
        } 
    }
}
```

Now you need a way to revert back the value of the boolean member variable back to `false`. You can reset in the `DialogInterface.OnClickListener` as per your business logic.

Answer (score 0):

To reset the OnClickListener of an EditText I tried:

```
View.OnClickListener defaultOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        v.requestFocus();
    }
};

...

editText.setOnClickListener(defaultOnClickListener);
```

and it seems to work fine!